# Regex to match all except word with symbol

Tags: regex

I am trying to parse unit test exception messages and separate them from the stack trace from st-out. The output is formatted like so:

```
  Message:
    Failed: expected invocation of Session.endDialog(It.isValue("login complete.")) exactly 1 times, invoked 0 times
     Configured setups:
     Session.endDialog(It.isValue("login complete."))

     Performed invocations:
     Session.sendTyping()
     Session.endDialog("Login complete.")

  Stack:
        at Object.<anonymous> (<some path>\<some file>.spec.ts:274:19)
        at fulfilled (<some path>\<some file>.spec.js:4:57)
        at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:228:7)
```

The important bits are:

- There is always a `Message:` preceded by 2 spaces, followed by a newline.
- What follows `Message:` is 1 or more lines of text possibly with consecutive newlines.
- There is always a `Stack:` preceded by 2 spaces, followed by a newline.
- What follows `Stack:` is 1 or more lines of stack trace type text.

The parser is a little complicated in that it is line based but supports loops and a different RegExp is needed to capture the various important parts for the message.

I have working expressions for everything, except for one. **Basically I need a RegEx to match anything after the line with `Message:` until the `Stack:`, one line at a time.**

Eg, it must match:

```
    Failed: expected invocation of Session.endDialog(It.isValue("login complete.")) exactly 1 times, invoked 0 times`
```

and

```
     Configured setups:
```

and

```
     Session.endDialog(It.isValue("login complete."))
```

etc, but not

```
  Stack:
```

I have tried using negative look-ahead with no luck, this is what I have so far:

**`\s+(?!Stack:).+`**

Comment: You say the parser is line based: how do you expect it to check context on different lines?

Comment: The set of RegExp patterns can be supplied and are used sequentially, so if and when the first pattern matches then then next one in the list is used to match etc. So you will know based on previous supplied regex what has been matched.

Comment: Then your description is too long and misleading. What do you need to match? A line that does not start with `Stack:`? `^(?!  Stack:$)` / `(?m)^(?!  Stack:$)`?

Comment: Well I still need to match the line, but yes I think I did not explain this problem very well :(

Comment: It seems `^(?! Stack:$)` and `(?m)^(?! Stack:$)` both just capture an empty string not the message on the line.

Comment: Yes, because this pattern can be used to return true or false. If you need the line, adding `.+` or `.*` is not a rocket science. You already have it in your pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the required pattern eventually:
`^(?!  Stack:)(.*)$`